# Do we have to rewrite the MAILTO after each cron command?

Tags: cron, email

As we know that MAILTO is used for receiving any mail related to the Cron job. In my case I have three commands to execute, do I need to add MAILTO three times even if the receiver mail id is the same for each of the three commands? My jobs are running on a CentOS machine.

```
MAILTO=x@y.com
./first-Command

MAILTO=x@y.com
./second-Command

MAILTO=x@y.com
./third-Command
```

Or mentioning the mail id only once will work in my situation? like this:

```
MAILTO=x@y.com
./first-Command

./second-Command

./third-Command
```

I'm new to the Cron tool. Any idea/hint in the right direction will do!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `MAILTO` variable, if set, is retrieved from the `crontab` file, so if it exists and is not `""` then it will be used for all subsequent jobs in that file, just like if you had created a shell script like your second example.

Therefore, setting it at the top of the `crontab` file is enough, just like you could change the `crontab` shell from `sh` to `bash` with `SHELL=/bin/bash` in the beginning of the file per the [man page](https://www.unix.com/man-page/centos/5/crontab/).

Answer (score 1):

One `MAILTO` per crontab file

[man cron](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/cron.8.html):

> When executing  commands,  any  output  is mailed  to  the  owner  of
> the  crontab  (or  to the user named in the MAILTO environment
> variable in the crontab, if such exists).

Comment: That quote doesn't seem to say anything to support your conclusion. It only says that the value of the `MAILTO` variable controls where the mail is sent, not how the value of the variable is determined, or how long an assignment is in effect.